# difference between thread/runnable, handler, runonuithread, asynctask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler

i started learning android programming and am working on a small game. i heard that doing background operations or updates or downloading or what ever background and time consuming thing should not be done with ui thread and instead use thread/runnable or asynctask. but i cant do some things in threads like background connectivity to database where as this connectivity works with the remaining handler,runonuithread,asynctask.am greatly confused where to use which one.
I have some questions
1.handler,runonuithread are both runs on ui thread, thread/runnable is a different thread and in async task, doinbackground method run on different thread and others methods like onprogressupdate,onpreexecute and onpostexecute run on ui thread. right?
if that so i wrote a program to do database connectivity with thread/runnable it didnt worked but when i wrote it in doinbackground it worked. my confusin is that as both those methods run on different thread why this is happening.
2.what is the main difference btw those 4 and where are they applicable and not applicable.
And also want to know what are the tasks which only ui thread can do.
thanks in adv:)

Comment: 1. It will be hard to tell without seeing what you are doing to access your database in the background thread, it is more likely you aren't setting up/running your thread right than it is it would work in an AsyncTask and not a thread, as an AsyncTask is simply a thread implementation that provides ui methods and handles thread management to avoid leaks.

Comment: 2. a handler acts like a link between your background thread and your ui thread, runonuithread allows you to attempt to run processes from a background thread on the ui thread, an asynctask is a thread implementation that Android developed to make thread interaction easier/avoid thread leaks, a thread gives you full control of running a background thread but you need to be careful managing it.

Comment: bro u r simple awesome @zgc7009. that was shot but very usefull matter. can u give me more detail of what u said in the 2.nd comment. and if u know what are the think only ui thread can do plz share it with me. and what do u mean by need to be carefull managing a thread/runnable? 
ty for this info

Comment: `Handler` - when you have a background thread, and you need to send a message from the background thread to the main ui thread to update the ui, trigger an event, etc, you send a message from your thread to your handler, your handler will receive the message and post it to your ui thread. `runOnUiThread()` - when you have a (usually) long running background thread process, but a piece of that needs to be performed on the ui thread, you use runOnUiThread(){} to perform that chunk of code in the main thread instead of the background thread.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is essentially a thread that manages the thread process/life cycle for you so that you don't run into any potential issues (like leaks, that are easy to happen if you aren't careful running your own thread), it also provides convenient ui methods that allow you to interact with the main ui thread as necessary (often to update the ui).

Comment: `Thread` is like the mother of all backend processes, it will do a great majority of the ui thread will do, but it CAN NOT interact with any of the ui (meaning there is no modification to your ui/views/layouts from the background thread), because of this threads can have handlers to interact with the ui; it is important to note that mismanaging a background thread can lead to leaks so if you can use an AsyncTask it is preferred.

Comment: Didn't post that as an answer cause I figure someone would come through and do a better job since those classes can each be explained in greater detail with appropriate links/examples.

Comment: but ur answer was gud. should have posted as answer rather than comments.

Comment: what happens if we make uithread to wait or suspend or sleep or join? will the program slow down?

Comment: You really don't want to wait, sleep, or suspend the ui thread in any case I can think of. Calling join is something you do to wait for the termination of a thread, but again is really only something you should do if you have a good understanding of thread management. I highly advise using AsyncTasks over threads where possible.

Comment: Do understand, when your main ui thread is held up (for example by a wait) your ui/the screen/your app gets held up with it. It essentially makes it seem like the app is frozen (though a process is working). That is the importance of background threads and ui thread intermediaries (like handlers).

Answer (score 5):

A `Handler` allows you to post messages to be executed on the main UI thread. `Activity#runOnUiThread(Runnable)` is a convenience method that uses a `Handler` internally to post a `Runnable` on the UI thread (see the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L5243-L5249)). `Handler`s are often used to synchronize events generated on background threads with the main UI thread. For example, since `View`s and other UI widgets can't be modified directly on a background thread, the background thread might instead post a message that makes those modifications on the main UI thread instead of in the background.

An `AsyncTask` is a utility class that uses a thread pool to execute tasks and provides helpful callback methods (i.e. `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute`, etc.) that are guaranteed to be executed on the main UI thread (in other words, it abstracts the idea of `Handler`s from the developer).

Comment: I like your point about the AsyncTask UI methods abstracting on the Handler.

Comment: umm...i didnt understood just that point. abstracting handlers idea?what does it mean

Comment: Whenever the `AsyncTask` needs to call one of the `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute`, etc. methods, it posts a message to have the methods executed on the main UI thread instead of invoking them directly from a background thread. It uses a `Handler` to do this.

Comment: oh great!! how does a handler call those methods.
`new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
handler.post(new Runnable() {
new asynctask().execute();
//some code
}}}.start();`
like this?

Comment: The source code for `AsyncTask` is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java). It creates its own `InternalHandler` class and then posts messages to the handler by calling `Handler#obtainMessage()` and `Message#sendToTarget()`.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I will try to give you the most simple explanation!

Thread is a class that enables you to use the groovy Multitasking. It's a standard Java class. Every Java environment (in your case Android) can use it.

Runnable is an interface that does almost the same as the Thread class, but it's a bit simpler. In order to use it, you just need to implement the method run().

Handler is a more fancy, Android specific variant of the Thread class. There are certain specific functions and other useful stuff.

RunOnUiThread is a method which gives us access to the main thread or a.k.a. UI Thread in Android! Yes, again this simple word Thread! Because in Android you CAN'T modify the UI from another Thread, except the main (or a.k.a. UI) Thread, Google has provided a method to access this thread.

AsyncTask the most valuable and cool class to extend! It's designed to simplify our life as developers and do the best job in Android environment. It can be considered again as a Thread, but "simplified" and "unified". This means that using AsyncTask is simple, easy and very useful!

---

AsyncTask is c00l that's why I will give you a short description:

To use it, it's a best practice to extend AsyncTask in your class. Than you need to implement 3 methods! Yes, just three!

The first is used as a "preparation". In this method all the things that are happening are BEFORE the new, parallel thread is started.

The second is used to DO your JOB in a new thread!!1

The last (third) is used to execute some tasks JUST AFTER you complete your work in the newly created Thread.

---

If you are interested enough I'm sure that you can find a dozens tutorials and examples explaining this to you, but my opinion is that you just need to try them all!

**REMEMBER**
The most important thing is to use a construction when it's most needed. Don't use complex structures when you can use a simpler one. And of course it's not coincidence that there is AsyncTask or Handler classes, they are meant to assist us!

Good luck and I hope this short and rubbish explanation is not too confusing.